One notation in one preparational lemma for the proof of Noether normalization theorem
I found this lemma  before Noether normalization theorem.

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $N$ be a finite nonempty set of multi-indices $\nu=(\nu_1,\ldots,\nu_n)$. Given $e=(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ we set $e\cdot \nu=\displaystyle \sum e_i\nu_i$. Then for $e_1 \gg e_2 \gg...\gg e_n$ we have: If $\nu,\nu'\in N$ then $$(e\cdot\nu=e\cdot\nu')\Leftrightarrow (\nu=\nu').$$

I am here to ask what '$\gg$' means. I usually understand $\gg$ means $$\text{sufficiently larger than}$$ but I do not think such meaning applies here. In the very beginning of chapter 10 in Stack Project, Johan listed all the notation he used but I did not find there either.

See Johan's comment here.

If we say $n \gg m$  then that translates into "$n$ is much larger than $m$" in the English language. Does that help?

The proof indeed makes the assumption $e_{i-1} > A_i e_i + A_{i+1} e_{i+1} + \cdots + A_n e_n$.
